# Using regular expressions with 'not' in .htaccess redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having difficulty with a regular expression that starts with a 'not' in an .htaccess redirect.

I have a Wordpress multisite (subdomain install) with a wildcard SSL certificate called webhive.com.au. Some blogs run on a webhive.com.au subdomain. Others have their own domain name.

I want to redirect all webhive.com.au URLs to https and all other URLs to http.

My .htaccess contains:

```
#Redirect *.webhive.com.au domains to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?webhive\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redirect non webhive domains to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*\.)?webhive\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The first block appears to work correctly, directing webhive.com.au domains to https. The second block doesn't.

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to redirect to HTTP, if HTTPS is available?

Comment: I have a wildcard SSL certificate for *.webhive.com.au. I don't have a certificate for other domains.

Comment: You can not redirect requests to `https://not-webhive.com.au`, if there is no SSL cert available that covers `not-webhive.com.au` - because the request will never even make it that far. The secure connection is established _before_ HTTP comes into play. The client will stop talking to your server, because the server can not present a valid SSL certificate for the requested host name - so client goes, “nah, this isn’t secure, Imma done talking to you & outta here.”

Comment: Yup, my browser gives a security error. Are you saying that I can't use .htaccess to redirect `https://not-webhive.com.au` to `http://not-webhive.com.au`?

Comment: That is what I said, yes.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a workaround?

This is an issue because after secure login via webhive.com.au, users receive a security error on their Wordpress dashboard if they have a non-Webhive domain.

Comment: Well the obvious workaround would be to _get_ certificates for all those domains. In times of Let’s Encrypt that doesn’t even have to cost anything any more. If this - a.k.a. the only sensible thing to do - is “not an option” - well then we’d need to know what the actual error is first, before we could possibly make suggestions ...

Comment: After login users access their website's dashboard via the Sites link. I see https://blogname.webhive.com.au flash up before the Domain Mapping plugin redirects the URL to https://blogdomain.com.au/wp-admin. 

Maybe the solution lies with Wordpress rather than .htaccess...

Comment: The multisite runs on Cpanel and I gather that you can't install more than one SSL certificate. (I've tried!) I'd have to get a SAN certificate. The cheapest I've found is about $40/domain per year and most of my customers won't want to pay that. Also, there's a maximum of 100 domains per SAN, which would prevent me from adding more websites into the multisite in the future.

Comment: Well then you have to solve it on the WP side somehow ... I’d check if the Domain Mapping plugin has any options to specify which sites can be accessed using HTTPS and which not.

Comment: You know what, that might just work! Found this option - 'Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if this redirect is disabled)'. Nice one! Will give it a go. Thanks @CBroe :)

Comment: That worked! Brilliant!!! So pleased! Thanks again @CBroe :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, the url which don't have `webhive.com.au` will not be redirected there is no need for second part.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?webhive\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But what if someone is browsing `https://not-webhive.com.au`? OP wants to redirect to http instead.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification @abhishek-gurjar but @ hjpotter92 is right. It's the non-webhive.com.au domains I need to redirect.

Comment: I still need to redirect other domains to http because I want people to log in securely via webhive.com.au. If I don't redirect non-Webhive domains, they'll get a security certificate error when they access their dashboard after login.